# PyMongo: Is there a way to add data to a existing document in MongoDB using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database 'Product'. Which contains a collection name 'ProductLog'. Inside this collection , there are 2 documents in the following format:

```json
  {
    "environment": "DevA",
    "data": [
      {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Stream": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ZYX",
        "Stream": "Yes"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "environment": "DevB",
    "data": [
      {
        "Name": "ABC",
        "Stream": "Yes"
      },
      {
        "Name": "ZYX",
        "Stream": "Yes"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This gets added as 2 documents in collection. I want to append more data in the already existing document's 'data' field in MongoDB using python. Is there a way for that? I guess update would remove the existing fields in "data" field or may update a whole document.

For example: Adding one more array in `EmployeeDetails` field, while the earlier data in `EmployeeDetail` also remains.

[image]

Comment: Would you clarify what you want to do?  You present documents in a `ProductLog` collection and state you want to add elements to the `data` array, and then you present a new, seemingly unrelated, document and mention adding to an array there that doesn't exist - `EmployeeDetails` isn't an array.

Comment: You can update a document in a collection using one of the update methods - `update_one` or `update_many` of PyMongo. To add sub-documents to the array field `data` use the `$push` update operator.

Answer (score 1):

I want to show how you can append more data in the already existing document 'data' field in MongoDB using python:

First install pymongo:

```
pip install mongoengine
```

Now let's get our hands dirty:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

mongo_uri = "mongodb://user:pass@mongosrv:27017/"
client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
database = client["Product"]
collection = "ProductLog"

database[collection].update_one({"environment": "DevB"}, {
    "$push": {
        "data": {"Name": "DEF", "Stream": "NO"}
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a SQL library in Python language through which you can insert/add your data in your desired database. For more information, check out the tutorial

Comment: Actually I need to add data to existing document.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).